# Angularjs Filter - remove character if appears more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace, slice

Been at this for  a couple of hours with no breakthrough.

I have a timeline with various minutes

4'
10'
etc

but some have appendages on them

5'+1'
8'+2'

I have set up the filter like so:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('addedTime', function(){
      return function(text) {
       var newText = text.replace(/\+.*$/, '<sup class="additional">$&</sup>');
       console.log(newText);

       return newText;
  };
});'
```

As you can see it adds a superscript to the addition time. However I want to remove the final ' (single quote) from that and I can't figure out how to do it without affecting the normal times (4', 6' etc).

I thought about splitting it completely and rejoining it but not sure if that would be worthwhile.. any advice is appreciated.

Edit:
essentially I am trying to get it to look like

```
<ul>
   <li>5'</li>
   <li>5'<sup>+2</sup></li>
<ul>
```

(notice the lack of single quote after the +2)

Comment: Can you show us your expected output when operation performed on `5'+1' 8'+2'`?

Comment: Perhaps `text.replace(/(\+\d+)(\')/g, '<sup class="additional">$1</sup>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using callbacks in `replace` ?

```
var newText = text.replace(/\+([0-9]*)\'/g, function(a) {
    return '<sup class="additional">'+a.substring(1, a.length - 1) +'</sup>'
});
```

You first discover the "added" times because they are a plus sign followed by a number and a quote. Then you modify this group.

Given `var text = "5'+1' 8'+2'";`
it returns

```
5'<sup class="additional">1</sup> 8'<sup class="additional">2</sup>
```

Another option:

```
var newText = text.replace(/\+(\d)\'/g, '<sup class="additional">$1</sup>')
```

returns `5'<sup class="additional">1</sup> 8'<sup class="additional">2</sup>`

Comment: var newText = text.replace(/\+(\d)\'/g, '<sup class="additional">$1</sup>')

works perfectly! I had solved it by splitting arrays, took 8 lines of code. This is much neater! Need to learn the regex replace in a lot more detail!